# How to get geo coordinates from GestureEventArgs using bing map control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, geolocation, bing

I have WP7 application and using Hold event. Is it possible to get geocoordinates for a point I'm holdin my finger on?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Point p = e.GetPosition(this.MapMain);
GeoCoordinate geo = new GeoCoordinate();
geo = MapMain.ViewportPointToLocation(p);
```

geo now contains coordinates of tap.

Comment: It is ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate instead of ViewportPointToLocation on WP8