# WP81 MapsTask get selected location

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, geofencing

I have a WP81 (Silverlight) that uses a GPS geofence background task. I want the user to select the location on where to create the geofence. For this, I currently provide two textboxes for Longitude and Latitude values of a geo coordinate. While this works fine, I guess users will be irritated because the expected behavior would be to provide an address or directly set a point on a map.

In order to provide a map where the user can select a given location I was searching for something like a chooser or launcher. The only launcher that I found is the MapsTask. Unfortunately, it is not possible to let the user select some location and get the geocoordinate back.

```
private void btnLaunchMapsTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MapsTask mapsTask = new Maps-Task();
    mapsTask.Center = new GeoCoordinate(51.5171, -0.1362); // London
    mapsTask.Show();
}
```

As you can see I can just open the map and provide a specific geocoordinate where to center the map.

Is there a way in Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) to provide a user with a map to select a location and get the geo coordinate back? Is it possible via MapsTask and I just don't see it? Is there another way (even 3rd party package on NuGet) to achieve this?

Comment: Best is to add a map control on your page and use the tap event to get the geolocation cfr - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526697/how-to-get-geo-coordinates-from-gestureeventargs-using-bing-map-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526697/how-to-get-geo-coordinates-from-gestureeventargs-using-bing-map-control)

Comment: I thought about the exact same solution but has hoped to find another, more convenient one

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SearchTerm property to solve this. Sample:

```
MapsTask maps = new MapsTask();
maps.ZoomLevel = 9;
maps.SearchTerm = "London";
maps.Show();
```